# Query, 'date is less than' not functioning right

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, query-builder

What's wrong with my query? Problem is somewhere in 'where' part.

```
$time_point = date('U') - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60; //month
$point = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_point);
$messages = Message::find()->where('<', 'date_time', $point)->all();
```

I want to find all messages that are older that one month. I get error like that:

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Illegal string offset ':qp1'

For me it looks perfectly normal, so I'm really surprised.
`$time_point` and `$point` have correct values.

Comment: Put `where()` condition in array.

Comment: i believe the operator `<` comes as second parameter in where(), not first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,,

```
$time_point = date('U') - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60; //month
$point = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_point);
$messages = Message::find()->where(['<', 'created_at', $point])->all();
```

hope help,,